# HMM model training issue in implementation

Tags: python, hidden-markov-model

I am attempting to train an HMM on a series of sequences but the resulting prediction of the hidden states returns no change over the time series.

My dataset is structured where the state begins in a certain state and at a certain point in each series, transitions to the other state. I have defined the state for each of the time series as but am not certain how to use this information in training the dataset.

I am using the [HMMLearn](https://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package in Python with a Gaussian Mixture Emission HMM (GMMHMM) and have the sequences selected and the associated lengths of each sequence but as I stated before, after training, the prediction shows no change over an example sequence.

seq_final.shape = (14758, 9)
len(lengths) = 311
sum(lengths) = 14758

Code:

```
model = hl.GMMHMM(n_mix=9, n_iter=300, n_components=2, tol=1e-3)
model.fit(seq_final, np.array(lengths))
```

The seq_final is a ~15000x9 np array broken up with the lengths array to delineate different sequences as instructed. I currently have not added the state to the dataset used to train but I think that is the aspect I am missing.

Edit: I am trying to implement the training set with supervised learning instead of unsupervised as it is not correctly predicting the state change and I don't know why.

Comment: Hi Evan and Welcome to CV. What is your question?

Comment: Why my output model doesn't predict a state change. The hidden state for these models are assumed for the datasets but when I use the training set, there is no change in state. I am trying to figure out how to account for the state in the training fit() method.

Comment: Great, but please add this information directly to your post. Comments in the future may be removed.

Comment: Can you plot your data, the output states, and indicate on the plot where you expected states to change (the desired behaviour)? Also to include how you are extracting the states

Comment: https://github.com/hmmlearn/hmmlearn/issues/338 looks like there is no implementation in this package